# how to implement resize animation with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, resize

When the container is resized,everything inside(text) should also scale accordingly.

Is there a plugin that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui.all.css"/>

<div id="container" class="ui-widget-content"
  style="font-size:10px;width:100px;height:100px;padding:0.5em;">         
    <div class="ui-widget-header">Resize This</div>
    this is some text. this is some text. this is some text. this is some 
    text. this is some text. this is some text. this is some text. this is 
    some text. this is some text. this is some text. this is some text.
</div>
```

jquery:

```
    var oh=0; //original height of container
    var ow=0; //original width of container
    var fs=10;//original font size

    $(document).ready(function(){
        oh=$("#container").height();
        ow=$("#container").width();

        $("div#container").resizable({
            stop: function(element,ui){
              var h=ui.size.height;
              if(oh==0) return;
              var nfs = (h/oh) *fs;
              $("#container").css({'font-size':nfs+"px"});
           },
           ghost: true
         });
    });
```

Comment: this can be optimized by placing the global vars inside the scope of the main function